# Angular-Material : How to set an Input field to a key value stored in chrome.storage

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, angular-material

I've been trying to figure out chrome storage all day. I have a chrome extension Pop-up that has an input field bound to a variable "myText". When the user presses the "Save Text" button, I have been able to successfully store whatever they typed into chrome storage. I am also able to read out the stored text with console.log(storedText)... However, for some reason I am not able to set the Input field to the stored text. I want the user to be able to click the "Restore" button and have the previously saved text fill the input box. I must be doing something pretty simple wrong, sorry for yet another noob question.
below is my code:
app.component.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Input</mat-label>
  <input matInput [(ngModel)]='myText'>
</mat-form-field>
<br>
<button mat-stroked-button (click)="saveChanges()" color='accent'>Save Text</button>
<button mat-stroked-button (click)="restore()" color='primary'>restore</button>
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent{
  title = 'dataStoreTest';
  myText = '';

  saveChanges() {
    chrome.storage.local.set({storedText: this.myText});
  }

  restore(){
    chrome.storage.local.get( ['storedText'], function(result){
      this.myText = result.storedText;     // <----- for whatever reason, this isn't changing myText at all
      console.log(result.storedText + ' has been restored'); // <----- This is still printing the expected result 
    });
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May your not getting reference of **this** in your functions, try this code or just try to change your function to arrow function.

```
  restore(){
    let self = this;
    chrome.storage.local.get( ['storedText'], function(result){
      self.myText = result.storedText; 
      console.log(result.storedText + ' has been restored');
    });
  }
```

Comment: OK, so now it is changing it.... but only when I push the button twice in a row. the first time it is pressed, nothing happens. The second time works perfectly. Do you have any idea why it might be doing that?

Comment: No sure man, something to do with asynchronous nature of chrome.storage.local.get().